Set correct height to section background view in horizontal collectionview
I am trying out the Modern collectionviews with the below code.
The only problem in this code is the section background height is filling from the last item . If I keep the collection view scrolling to vertical that works correctly.
class SectionDecorationViewController: UIViewController {

    static let sectionBackgroundDecorationElementKind = "section-background-element-kind"

    var currentSnapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Int>! = nil
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Int>! = nil
    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
    var currentSelection: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Section Background Decoration View"
        configureHierarchy()
        configureDataSource()
    }
}

extension SectionDecorationViewController {
    /// - Tag: Background
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {

        let sectionProvider = { [weak self] (sectionIndex: Int,
                                 layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in



            guard let self = self else { return nil }

            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                                  heightDimension: .absolute(44))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

            // Get the number of items in the section
            let itemCount = self.currentSnapshot.numberOfItems(inSection: sectionIndex)

            // Custom group height based on the number of items
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                                   heightDimension: .absolute(CGFloat(itemCount) * 44))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .paging
            section.interGroupSpacing = 0 // Remove inter-group spacing
            section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0) // Remove content insets

            // Add the background decoration item
            let sectionBackgroundDecoration = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(
                elementKind: SectionDecorationViewController.sectionBackgroundDecorationElementKind)
            section.decorationItems = [sectionBackgroundDecoration]
            return section
        }
        
        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        config.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        config.interSectionSpacing = 0
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(
            sectionProvider: sectionProvider, configuration: config)
        layout.register(
            SectionBackgroundDecorationView.self,
            forDecorationViewOfKind: SectionDecorationViewController.sectionBackgroundDecorationElementKind)
        return layout
    }
}

extension SectionDecorationViewController {
    func configureHierarchy() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
    func configureDataSource() {
        
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<ListCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, identifier) in
            // Populate the cell with our item description.

            cell.label.text = "\(indexPath.section),\(indexPath.item)"

        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Int>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            // Return the cell.
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier)
        }

        // initial data
        let itemsPerSection = 5
        let sections = Array(0..<5)
        currentSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Int>()
        var itemOffset = 0
        sections.forEach {
            currentSnapshot.appendSections([$0])
            currentSnapshot.appendItems(Array(itemOffset..<itemOffset + itemsPerSection))
            itemOffset += itemsPerSection
        }
        dataSource.apply(currentSnapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}




Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77297540/6257435

Nope becuase the issue is when you specify scrollDirection = .horizontal

Based on this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77297540/6257435 - with just a few modifications, and stripped-down to emphasize group backgrounds when .scrollDirection = .horizontal...

Simple Cell class - single label, centered:
class SimpleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    
}


Section Background View class:
class SectionBackgroundView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "SectionBackgroundView"
    
    let bkgView = UIView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
        bkgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(bkgView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bkgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        bkgView.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.5, green: 0.75, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        bkgView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        bkgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        bkgView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }
    
}


Example Controller class:
class HorizontalGroupsVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Int>! = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
        ])
        
        configureDataSource()
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    static let backgroundElementKind = "background-element-kind"
    
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                              heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(80.0),
                                               heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 8
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8)
        
        section.decorationItems = [
            NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: HorizontalGroupsVC.backgroundElementKind)
        ]
        
        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        config.interSectionSpacing = 12
        
        config.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section, configuration: config)
        
        layout.register(SectionBackgroundView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: HorizontalGroupsVC.backgroundElementKind)
        
        return layout
    }
    
    func configureDataSource() {
        
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<SimpleCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, identifier) in
            cell.theLabel.text = "\(indexPath)"
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Int>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier)
        }
        
        // initial data
        let itemsPerSection: [Int] = [3, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
        let sections = Array(0..<itemsPerSection.count)
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Int>()
        var itemOffset = 0
        var i: Int = 0
        
        sections.forEach {
            snapshot.appendSections([$0])
            let n = itemsPerSection[i % itemsPerSection.count]
            snapshot.appendItems(Array(itemOffset..<itemOffset + n))
            itemOffset += n
            i += 1
        }
        
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
    
}


Output:


I tried you solution but there is no change and in end result. At first I saw the same as in the screenshots provided but as soon as I changed the group size the section height does not change with it and remains that of the collectionview height .

@harshalb - that is correct. If you are using a collection view with .scrollDirection = .horizontal, the collection view scrolls horizontally. You can change the height of your design so it looks like this if you want (the red rect is the scrollView frame): https://i.sstatic.net/pBRjD1Jf.png ... but wouldn't it make more sense to set the height of the scroll view?

I want to make a list section vertical and scroll horizontal so if I need to add one more item to the list it should grow vertically as well . I was able to achieve that as well except the background view . If I set the collection view height then if there is some text that grows it will be out of bounds.

@harshalb - "a list section vertical and scroll horizontal" ... well, that's not what you asked. So, at this point, it is not clear what you are really trying to accomplish. Instead of showing images of what you don't want, mock up some images showing what you DO want (and do a better job of describing your goal).

@harshalb - are you still trying to find a solution (that this answer doesn't solve)?
