How to dynamically add rows to UITableviewCell in efficient manner?
I need to have UI structure where my table cell can have text (that is easy to implement as it will automatically increase table cell height) and also can have multiple records shown in below image:

I have done some R&D and have gone through possible solutions:
(1) Adding views dynamically inside stack view of UiTableViewCell
This is a good solution but the issue is, on appear on the cell the views needs to be removed and added again that will have very slow scrolling
(2) Take UITableView inside UITableViewCell
This will be misuse of UITableView as it will be reloaded recursively and also setting dynamic heights will be also challenging.
Is there any efficient solution in terms of height calculation and performance? Can I disable UITableViewCell dequeuing so the subviews will not be removed and added again?

Just a suggestion, I don't know what you've already tried.
You could use one single table view and add different sections where:

ingredients and steps are first section
items added are second section

Then you can handle everything in a single place

But in that case, it will be not possible to show background (buble)

@NSPratik - you can do this with a multi-section table view... it just requires a little creativity to make it look like groups of cells have a "bubble background." The option of using repeating views in a UIStackView in a single cell can work, by showing/hiding the arranged subviews instead of removing/re-adding them every time. Do you have a reasonable "max number" of items to show? Or, is it possible a single recipe could have hundreds of items?

@NSPratik - instead of UITableView you could go with a UICollectionView with compositional layout... This Q&A may get you headed in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77297540/6257435

@DonMag Can height of cells be dynamic if i use compositional layout? For example, rows like [0,0], [0,1] should grow based on its content. In my case, the ingredient name can be larger so that it needs more than 1 line

@NSPratik - sure, cell heights can be dynamic.

One approach is using a UICollectionView with multiple sections and Compositional Layout, and implementing "background-element-kind" supplementary views.
It can look like this:



Here is some very quick sample code...

// MARK: data structures
struct MyIngredient {
    var imgName: String = "0.circle.fill"
    var desc: String = "Description"
    var subDesc: String = "Sub Description"
    var selected: Bool = true
}
struct MyRecipe {
    var recipeName: String = "Name"
    var recipe: String = "Recipe"
    var ingredients: [MyIngredient] = []
}

// MARK: a class to generate some sample data
class SampleData: NSObject {
    
    let rStr: String = "This is the recipe description. For now, every recipe will be the same, just with a different number of ingredients.\n\nIngredients:"
    
    func genSampleData() -> [MyRecipe] {
        var ret: [MyRecipe] = []
        
        let iCounts: [Int] = [2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3]
        var tmpStr: String
        
        for (r, n) in iCounts.enumerated() {
            var myR = MyRecipe()
            myR.recipeName = "Recipe \(r)"
            tmpStr = rStr
            var ings: [MyIngredient] = []
            for i in 0..<n {
                var ing = MyIngredient()
                ing.imgName = "\(i).circle.fill"
                ing.desc = "Ingredient \(i)"
                if i == 1 {
                    ing.desc = "Ingredient \(i) has a long enough name to need to wrap."
                }
                ing.subDesc = "\(i) cups"
                ings.append(ing)
                tmpStr += "\n - Ingredient \(i)"
            }
            myR.recipe = tmpStr
            myR.ingredients = ings
            ret.append(myR)
        }
        
        return ret
        
    }
    
}

// MARK: Recipe Cell
class RecipeCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "recipeCell"
    
    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .regular)
        v.textColor = .white
        return v
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
        ])
    }
}

// MARK: Ingredient Cell
class IngredientCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "ingredientCell"
    
    let descLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .regular)
        v.text = "desc"
        return v
    }()
    let subDescLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .light)
        v.text = "subdesc"
        return v
    }()
    let imgView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.tintColor = .red
        return v
    }()
    let checkView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.tintColor = .systemGreen
        return v
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        let labelStack = UIStackView()
        labelStack.axis = .vertical
        labelStack.spacing = 4.0
        for v in [imgView, labelStack, checkView] {
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        labelStack.addArrangedSubview(descLabel)
        labelStack.addArrangedSubview(subDescLabel)

        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // avoid auto-layout complaints
        let c = imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 54.0)
        c.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
            c,
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.heightAnchor),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            checkView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0),
            checkView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkView.widthAnchor),
            checkView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            checkView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            labelStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.trailingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            labelStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkView.leadingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            labelStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            labelStack.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            labelStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])
        
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        contentView.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark") {
            checkView.image = img
        }
    }
    func fillData(ing: MyIngredient) {
        imgView.backgroundColor = .clear
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: ing.imgName) {
            imgView.image = img
        } else {
            imgView.backgroundColor = .red
        }
        descLabel.text = ing.desc
        subDescLabel.text = ing.subDesc
        checkView.isHidden = !ing.selected
    }
}

// MARK: Section Header reusable view
class SecHeaderSupplementaryView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "SecHeaderSupplementaryView"
    
    let recipeLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .bold)
        v.textColor = .white
        v.text = "name"
        return v
    }()
    let ingredientsLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .regular)
        v.textColor = .white
        v.text = "I've added the items below to your bag:"
        return v
    }()
    let bkgView = UIView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        
        for v in [bkgView, recipeLabel, ingredientsLabel] {
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(v)
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            recipeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            recipeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            recipeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            recipeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            ingredientsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            ingredientsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            ingredientsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            ingredientsLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            bkgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 14.0),
            bkgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
        ])
        
    }
}

// MARK: Section Footer reusable view
class SecFooterSupplementaryView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "SecFooterSupplementaryView"
    
    let bkgView = UIView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        
        var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        cfg.title = "Section Footer Button"
        cfg.baseBackgroundColor = .white
        cfg.baseForegroundColor = .blue
        let btn = UIButton(configuration: cfg)
        
        for v in [bkgView, btn] {
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(v)
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.centerXAnchor),
            btn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.centerYAnchor),
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.topAnchor),
            btn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgView.bottomAnchor),
            
            bkgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            bkgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
        ])
        
    }
}

// MARK: Section Background reusable view
class SectionBackgroundView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "SectionBackgroundView"
    
    let bkgView = UIView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
        bkgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(bkgView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bkgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        bkgView.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.342, green: 0.375, blue: 0.918, alpha: 1.0)
        bkgView.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
    }
    
}

// MARK: Example controller
class BorderedSectionsVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var theData: [MyRecipe] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let lay = createLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: lay)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(cv)
        
        // inset the collection view a bit - adjust as desired
        let pad: CGFloat = 20.0
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: pad),
            cv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: pad),
            cv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -pad),
            cv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -pad),
        ])
        
        cv.register(RecipeCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: RecipeCell.reuseIdentifier)
        cv.register(IngredientCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: IngredientCell.reuseIdentifier)
        
        cv.register(SecHeaderSupplementaryView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: BorderedSectionsVC.sectionHeaderElementKind, withReuseIdentifier: SecHeaderSupplementaryView.reuseIdentifier)
        cv.register(SecFooterSupplementaryView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: BorderedSectionsVC.sectionFooterElementKind, withReuseIdentifier: SecFooterSupplementaryView.reuseIdentifier)
        cv.register(SectionBackgroundView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: BorderedSectionsVC.backgroundElementKind, withReuseIdentifier: SectionBackgroundView.reuseIdentifier)
        
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self

        // generate some sample data
        theData = SampleData().genSampleData()
        
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // we will alternate Recipe and Ingredients List sections, so
        //  return double the number of data elements
        return theData.count * 2
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // if it's an even-numbered section, it's a Recipe Section
        //  else, it's an Ingredients List Section
        let dataIndex = section / 2
        if section % 2 == 0 {
            return 1
        }
        return theData[dataIndex].ingredients.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // if it's an even-numbered section, it's a Recipe Section
        //  else, it's an Ingredients List Section
        let dataIndex = indexPath.section / 2
        if indexPath.section % 2 == 0 {
            let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: RecipeCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RecipeCell
            c.theLabel.text = theData[dataIndex].recipe
            return c
        }
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: IngredientCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! IngredientCell
        c.fillData(ing: theData[dataIndex].ingredients[indexPath.item])
        return c
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind {
        case BorderedSectionsVC.sectionHeaderElementKind:
            // if it's an even-numbered section, it's a Recipe Section
            //  else, it's an Ingredients List Section
            let dataIndex = indexPath.section / 2
            let v = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: SecHeaderSupplementaryView.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SecHeaderSupplementaryView
            v.recipeLabel.text = theData[dataIndex].recipeName
            v.recipeLabel.isHidden = indexPath.section % 2 == 1
            v.ingredientsLabel.isHidden = !v.recipeLabel.isHidden
            return v
            
        case BorderedSectionsVC.sectionFooterElementKind:
            let v = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: SecFooterSupplementaryView.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SecFooterSupplementaryView
            return v
            
        default:
            fatalError("unknown kind")
        }
    }
    
    static let sectionHeaderElementKind = "section-header-element-kind"
    static let sectionFooterElementKind = "section-footer-element-kind"
    static let backgroundElementKind = "background-element-kind"
    
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        
        // to allow auto-sizing variable-height cells,
        //  set both itemSize and groupSize heights to .estimated
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                              heightDimension: .estimated(60.0))
        
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                               heightDimension: .estimated(60.0))
        
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 6
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 6, trailing: 0)
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 20, bottom: 8, trailing: 20)
        
        let headerFooterSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                                      heightDimension: .estimated(44))
        
        let sectionHeader = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(
            layoutSize: headerFooterSize,
            elementKind: BorderedSectionsVC.sectionHeaderElementKind, alignment: .top)
        
        let sectionFooter = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(
            layoutSize: headerFooterSize,
            elementKind: BorderedSectionsVC.sectionFooterElementKind, alignment: .bottom)
        
        section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [sectionHeader, sectionFooter]
        
        section.decorationItems = [
            NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: BorderedSectionsVC.backgroundElementKind)
        ]
        
        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        config.interSectionSpacing = 12 // section spacing
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section, configuration: config)
        
        layout.register(SectionBackgroundView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: BorderedSectionsVC.backgroundElementKind)
        
        return layout
    }
    
}

Note: I put this together very quickly, with a lot of hard-coded values... it is Sample Code Only and is meant to give you a starting point.

This is awesome and I really appreciate. I am going to try and will come back to you. One thing I will have to ask that it is a chat UI, so if I keep trailing padding to collection view, it should work. I will check it

This works fine and I also learnt a lot from this. The thing I am stuck is I need sender cell to have leading padding and receiver cell to have trailing padding..

@NSPratik - "I need sender cell to have leading padding and receiver cell to have trailing padding" -- well, that is a completely different question. If this answer helped you accomplish this task, you should Accept it and move on. With a little searching you'll find many, many examples of how to setup cells for "sender/receiver" alignment.

Answer upvoted & accepted as it resolves my issue!
